# Root shell spawning

Tags: c, shell, privileges

I currently study a book about security (I didn't post the book's name because I am not sure about site rules but I can do it if there is no problem with that) and I came across a sample of code who's purpose is to spawn a root shell.

```
int main(){
  char *name[2];
  name[0] = "/bin/sh";
  name[1] = 0x0;
  execve(name[0], name, 0x0); 
  exit(0);
 }
```

I compile it using `gcc shell.c -o shell` and then run it, but what I get back is a common shell `$` instead of a root shell`#`. Could you tell me why?

Comment: short answer: you won't simply elevate your priviledges by running `sh`. You'd have to run it as `root` first.

Answer (score 4):

Because you forgot to read the part where you need to make the executable owned by root and setuid before it will do what you want.

Comment: No I didn't. `[jack@0day local]$ gcc shellcode.c -o shellcode`  
`[jack@0day local]$ ./shellcode`  
`sh-2.05b#`. Thats the exact books instuctions.

Comment: Then you need to find a new book, because there is no way that code would have that result.

Comment: i actually added `chown root <my_pro>`,`sudo chmod +s <my-prog>` following your advice and it worked.Thanks!